# Floating point zoom and setZoom in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) says that .zoom and setZoom() expect numbers. Everything would seem to point to these numbers being integers. However, today I gave the latter a floating point value and it worked ... sort of.

```
var MAP;

function initialize() {
    MAP = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
    {
        zoom : 5,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(-25.610111, 134.354806), 
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}
```

Using the above code, I was able to have debugger access to the MAP object.

Now in the case of continental Australia, if I have a zoom of 4, I get a slice of South East Asia, all of Papua New Guinea and New Zealand and, in the centre, the Great Southern Land. If I have a zoom of 5 I get the mainland but without Tasmania -- definitely a "bad thing". The optimal zoom, discovered using MAP.setZoom() interactively, is 4.3. This is great, except that nothing else works with that zoom. When I try to draw polygons or a heatmap, Maps throws errors like

```
GET https://khms0.google.com/kh?v=178&hl=en-US&x=0&y=0&z=0.2999999999999998&token=77820 404 (OK)
```

I imagine that the 'z' value above is what's causing the 404 -- khms0.google.com is not expecting a floating point 'z' value.

So how do I get a more appropriately zoomed homeland, with polygons, markers, heatmaps, KML layers and what have you?

By the way, I did try using fitBounds() but it didn't change anything with respect to the visible contents of the viewport apart from shifting the map around a new centre.

```
var se = new google.maps.LatLng(-44.999315, 156.971343); // Tasman Sea
var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(-9.063496, 106.346343); // Indian Ocean
var bs = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(nw,se);
MAP.fitBounds(bs);
```

Answer (score 2):

The zoom level must be an integer (at least at present). It used to be documented, but I don't see it stated specifically anywhere.

If a integer zoom level doesn't work for you, either change the size of the `<div>` displaying the map or make your own custom tiles that have a different scale.